# I am using ffmpeg library in my program to record video and audio

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg, codec

I want to record video coming from a camcorder to a wmv file.  I am using ffmpeg libraries and I have it saving the video as an "avi" file.  However the requirements of the project is to output a wmv file.  Can anyone help me discover how to set up the video and audio codecs?

Comment: If you can share the code you have creating the AVI file it may make it easier for people to help. Also, WMV files can support a variety of codecs so it may be worth specifying which you need to support if you have a preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure for video codec as MPEG4 and audio codec as Windows media audio 2 to get the .wmv file format.

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 2M -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 output.wmv
```

When you use ffmpeg to generate WMV format the output video quality may be slightly less than other format. So it is better to set the qscale value to get better quality video.

Comment: This looks like a command line to convert a file.  That is not what I need.  I need C++ code to capture the video/audio and store it as a wmv file.  As I stated before, I have the codec configurations for AVI, but I need to store as WMV.